# Intercept (and redirect) style sheet, image and font loads from Gecko

Tags: c#, css, firefox, gecko, geckofx

I have a C# application using geckofx, as title says, I wish to intercept and redirect loading of images, fonts and style sheets (probably to be loaded from a DataBase)
I have tried using SetParentURIContentListener, but that is only activated for main page
any advice welcome

Comment: Can you say more? Is the source of the pages the internet, or your application? Our app runs its own little server to deliver all requests to the gecko browser in the same app.

Comment: The source of my pages is indeed my application The application is based on Gecko and is a prototype for an ad taking app that will use (probably)ckeditor to create and edit advertisements for print and online use. The ads need to be able to access a predetermined set of
1.Style Sheets
2.Images
3.Fonts The app will construct the original HTMl (or load it from the DataBase). I wish to specify URL's to reference the Style Sheets, Fonts and images and have the app load them as required (hnce the need to intercept and redirect loading)

Answer (score 0):

The source of my pages is indeed my application
The application is based on Gecko and is a prototype for an ad taking app that will use (probably)ckeditor to create and edit advertisements for print and online use. The ads need to be able to access a predetermined set of

1. Style Sheets
2. Images
3. Fonts
   The app will construct the original HTMl (or load it from the DataBase). I wish to specify URL's to reference the Style Sheets, Fonts and images and have the app load them as required (hnce the need to intercept and redirect loading)